# Different storage paths in Mongo Shell and when I use mongod command

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Open the links below.
It is showing /var/lib/mongodb in mongo shell:
[image: It is showing /var/lib/mongodb in mongo shell]

Here in mongod command it is /data/db:
[image: Here in mongod command it is /data/db]

How to make both of them same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mongo shell example says it's bound to port 127.0.0.1:27017.
The one where you start mongo by hand says it's bound to 127.0.0.1:27018.

You have two Mongo servers running, each on a different port and thus assumedly with a different configuration. Shut down the one you don't need – I'd guess the one on 27017 is one that's managed by your Ubuntu installation, and you can use the usual Systemd service management commands to stop it. (Naturally this may cause software expecting there to be a Mongo on 127.0.0.1:27017 to fail.)

Comment: But how can I change storage path as they both are different? Does it matter?

Comment: Also when I created a simple document and added to database using node app.js ,then if I go to mongo shell and when I use show dbs it's not listing my database which I created and added document using node.

Comment: You are connecting to two different Mongo servers. You absolutely _can't_ have both servers running and pointed to the same data directory; choose which you want to run and don't run the other.

Comment: Okay Thank you . Actually I am new to running servers and related stuff.